# Powershell, WinForms and modal popup with faded background

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to implement a PowerShell form whereby there is a faded overlay over the background desktop.

The only way I could think implementing this was to use two forms - one to show a full screen overlay (background form), and the other being the actual (main) form.  However, when i click off (or deactivate) the main form, I want everything to close.  However it no longer closes and I can't figure it why?  I get the feeling that when I click off the main form, the click event is trying to click the background form (and can't due to the main form having focus) and the 'deactivate' event no longer works?

Any help appreciated:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$windowsGreyTrans = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(20,43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOff = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOn = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(60,60,60)

$bgform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$bgform.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$bgform.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$bgform.MaximizeBox = $false
$bgform.Opacity = 0.5
$bgform.ControlBox = $false
$bgform.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::none

[void]$bgform.show()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$form.Name ="Power"
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.ControlBox = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::none

$shutdownBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$shutdownBtn.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
$shutdownBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$shutdownBtn.Text = "Shut down"
$shutdownBtn.FlatStyle = "Flat"
$shutdownBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$shutdownBtn.BackColor = $windowsGreyOff
$shutdownBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
$shutdownBtn.ForeColor = "White"
$shutdownBtn.Font = "Segoe UI,10pt"
#$shutdownBtn.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand

$shutdownBtn.Add_Click({         
    try {
    }
    catch{
        
    }
})

$shutdownBtn.Add_MouseEnter({
    $this.BackColor = $windowsGreyOn
})
$shutdownBtn.Add_MouseLeave({
    $this.BackColor = $windowsGreyOff
})

$form.Controls.Add($shutdownBtn)

$form.Add_Deactivate({    
    $this.Close()
    $bgform.close()
})

$form.Add_Shown({
   $this.Activate()
})

[void]$form.showdialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose you a better solution, use a tablelayoutpanel for center your button and intercept click event.

Try this :

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$windowsGreyTrans = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(20,43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOff = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOn = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(60,60,60)

#create form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.SuspendLayout()
$form.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.Opacity = 0.5
$form.ControlBox = $false
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::none

#create Tablelayout panel on this form
$TableLayoutPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$TableLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout()
$TableLayoutPanel.ColumnCount=1
$TableLayoutPanel.RowCount=1
$TableLayoutPanel.Dock=[System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill

$form.Controls.Add($TableLayoutPanel)

#create button on this tablelayoutpanel
$shutdownBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$shutdownBtn.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)
$shutdownBtn.Text = "Shut down"
$shutdownBtn.FlatStyle = "Flat"
$shutdownBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$shutdownBtn.BackColor = $windowsGreyOff
$shutdownBtn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
$shutdownBtn.ForeColor =[System.Drawing.Color]::White
$shutdownBtn.Font = "Segoe UI,10pt"
$shutdownBtn.Anchor=[System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::None

$TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($shutdownBtn)

#Layout
$TableLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout($false)
$form.ResumeLayout($false)

$shutdownBtn.Add_Click({         
    try {
    
    }
    catch{
        
    }
})

#change color to tablelayot on first show
$form.Add_Shown({         
    $TableLayoutPanel.BackColor =$windowsGreyTrans
})

$TableLayoutPanel.Add_Click({         
    $form.close()
})

$shutdownBtn.Add_MouseEnter({
    $this.BackColor = $windowsGreyOn
})
$shutdownBtn.Add_MouseLeave({
    $this.BackColor = $windowsGreyOff
})



[void]$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works well from a clicking perspective.  I guess the only disadvantage is that the buttons are transparent too, but if i give them darker shades of grey it may not matter too much....

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to stack two buttons on top of each other?  It's a bit of a pain not being able to specify locations....

Comment: Managed to do it i the end.  Two rows, 50% height.  Top button aligned bottom, and the bottom button aligned top!  Thanks.

Comment: Happy for you :) Good day to you !