# Powershell: How to force a window to be interacted with when it pops up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, modal-dialog, amazon-workspaces

Long time lurker, first time poster. I've come across a bit of a problem so I figured I'd ask for help.

I'm following [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/desktop-and-application-streaming/generate-logon-messages-for-security-and-compliance-in-amazon-windows-workspaces/) in order to get a popup message to appear once a user logs into an AWS workspace.

The script fully works, but the issue is that the window is able to be moved/resized and the user can still use the computer while the window is up.

I want to modify the script so that the popup window is FORCED to be interacted with (I.E. Click "OK" or "Logoff") before the user can click anything else on the computer.

How can this be done?

NOTE: I CAN NOT use the Interactive Login: Logon Text/Title GPO settings as it won't work in AWS workspaces.

Below is the code provided by AWS:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing");
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms");

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form;

# Removes the minimize, maximize and exit boxes from the top of the form.
$objForm.ControlBox = $False

$objForm.Text = "Security and Legal Notice";
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(640,480);
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen";

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True;
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
    {$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
    {$objForm.Close();logoff}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,400);
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23);
$OKButton.Text = "OK";
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()});
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton);

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,400);
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23);
$CancelButton.Text = "Logoff";
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close();logoff});
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton);

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label;
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20);
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400);
$objLabel.Text = "You are accessing a restricted system for official use only.

By selecting OK you agree to abide by all organizational security policies.

Do not allow unauthorized personnel to access this system."
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel);

$objForm.Topmost = $True;

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()});
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell, WinForms and modal popup with faded background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246629/powershell-winforms-and-modal-popup-with-faded-background)

Comment: This is what 'Modal Dialogs' are for, and you are not doing that. You are creating your own form to function like a dialog box, thus not the appropriate option. [powershell model dialog box](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+model+dialog+box%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: @postanote I didnt create this script, it was provided by AWS...I don't even have to use this script, I can use anything as long as its a textbox that pops up upon first login and requires the user to acknowledge the box before they can do anything else on the system.

Comment: @AnonCoward I just tested the code in the main text box of that thread and that does exactly what I want it to, the only difference is the "Shut Down" box needs to be the text box that I have in my original post. How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: You should be able to change the string `"Shut down"` in the answer to whatever text you need.

Comment: @AnonCoward that did it!!! Added the below code just after line 3 of my code, this added the transparency

$windowsGreyTrans = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(20,43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOff = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(43,43,43)
$windowsGreyOn = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(60,60,60)

$bgform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$bgform.WindowState = 'Maximized'
$bgform.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$bgform.MaximizeBox = $false
$bgform.Opacity = 0.5
$bgform.ControlBox = $false
$bgform.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::none

[void]$bgform.show()"

Comment: The steps you are using and have been pointed to, do not satisfy your used case as stated. ***'I want to modify the script so that the popup window is FORCED to be interacted with (I.E. Click "OK" or "Logoff") before the user can click anything else on the computer.'*** I can start any app using the WInKey I choose and ALT+Tab (including the PS instance that launched it) to it, thus interacting with it, regardless of what you have discovered here. Just saying, Now most users may never realize this, so, you should be safe with it, but just wanted you to know.